# Why can't I combine justify-content-center and justify-content-lg-left in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a **Bootstrap 4 Jumbotron** containing a column, set at different grid widths depending on breakpoint.

That's great, but I also want to set the column to **left** or **center**, within the row that wraps it, depending on the breakpoint: **center** at up to `md` inclusive, **left** at `lg` and up.

The class `justify-content-center` on the `row` correctly brings the column to the middle...

[image]

and I think just using the class `justify-content-lg-left` should push it back to the **left** of the **Jumbotron** at `lg` screen size, but it just stays in the middle, like in the above pic.

I also tried putting the center only with `justify-content-md-center`, but at `lg` size still would not go left.

How can I combine responsiveness on `justify` in the same way as I do for `col-*`?

**CODE**

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid-flex text-white mb-0 rounded-0">
  <div class="container-fluid py-5">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-lg-left">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center col-md-9 text-lg-left col-lg-8 pl-lg-3 align-self-center bg-warning">
        <h1 class="text-dark">My column content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the correct class in this case is `justify-content-lg-start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not `justify-content-left` class, the correct name for it is `justify-content-start`. Read [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content) and check next example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-white mb-0 rounded-0">
  <div class="container-fluid py-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center col-md-9 text-lg-left col-lg-8 pl-lg-3 align-self-center bg-warning">
        <h1 class="text-dark">My column content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note also:

**(1)** `jumbotron-fluid-flex` do not exists on Bootstrap. Maybe you wanted both: `jumbotron-fluid` and `d-flex`.

**(2)** Class `d-flex` on `row` elements are redundant, they already have flex properties.

Comment: D'oh. Yes. Not left - justify-content-lg-start

Answer (score 1):

Try opening this in **full screen**

The correct classes for justifying content in Bootstrap are:

- justify-content-start
- justify-content-end
- justify-content-center
- justify-content-around
- justify-content-between

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid-flex   text-white mb-0 rounded-0 " >
    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center   col-md-9  text-lg-left   col-lg-8 pl-lg-3  align-self-center bg-warning">
          <h1 class="text-dark">My column content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```